# The best way to get lines in a file in order?

Tags: c#, file, getline

Up to now, I know 2 way to get some lines of a file *(contains about 30.000 lines)*:

```
int[] input = { 100, 50, 377, 15, 26000, 5000, 15000, 30, ... };
string output = "";
for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{
    output += File.ReadLines("C:\\file").Skip(input[i]).Take(1).First();
}
```

or

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("C\\file");

int[] input = { 100, 50, 377, 15, 26000, 5000, 15000, 30, ... };
string output = "";
for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{
    output += lines[input[i]];
}
```

Lines I want to get need be order by input array.

**The first way**, I dont need make a `lines array`, which contains 30.000 elements (~4MB), but I must `re-open file for each element` of input.

**The second way**, I only need `read file one time`, but must `make an array` with large data.

There is any way I can get the lines better? Thank!

Comment: Perhaps using streams will lead you to find a more scalable solution?

Comment: To be honest I'm not seeing that much wrong with the second option, of reading the entire file in.  4mb is not a massive file and as long as the memory is released after you used it then I'd go with that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create buffered iterator, which will iterate sequence only once and keep buffer of required size:

```
public class BufferedIterator<T> : IDisposable
{
    List<T> buffer = new List<T>();
    IEnumerator<T> iterator;

    public BufferedIterator(IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        iterator = source.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public T GetItemAt(int index)
    {
        if (buffer.Count > index) // if item is buffered
            return buffer[index]; // return it
        // or fill buffer with next items
        while(iterator.MoveNext() && buffer.Count <= index)        
            buffer.Add(iterator.Current);
        // if we have read all file, but buffer has not enough items
        if (buffer.Count <= index)
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException(); // throw

        return buffer[index]; // otherwise return required item
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
       if (iterator != null)
           iterator.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines("C\\file");
using (var iterator = new BufferedIterator<string>(lines))
{
    int[] input = { 100, 50, 377 };
    for(int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        output += iterator.GetItemAt(input[i]);
}
```

With this sample only first 377 lines of file will be read and buffered, and file lines will be enumerated only once.

Comment: Thank you! Your solution is better than mine. One question: below answer suggest me use stream reader. If I use it then move offset to the line I need, is that only read the lines in input[] and importanly, faster? (I'm new to C# so I dont know which is better).

Comment: Memory stream is simply Stream class, which keeps all data in array. It is useful when you need to work with stream, but you don't want to use file, network or some other stream resource. It cannot be faster, then reading items to array and indexing array, because it keeps array internally

Comment: Ok, Thank for your help! Accepted the answer :)

Comment: @TuyenTk One suggestion - before starting to get lines from file, consider to analyze what is biggest line number you will need. I.e. `input.Max()`. If it is lower or much lower, than total lines count (30000), then it's better to use buffered reading. Otherwise just read all lines to array, as you did in second option (it also faster than MemoryStream)

Comment: Yes, my input.Max() may some time very small compare with file lines count. I'll check it before read lines. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This article shows how to read from a file using a memorystream. You can use it to buffer sections of the file at a time maybe using a carriage return as a delimiter http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/164372/Back-to-Basics-Reading-a-File-into-Memory-Stream